# Sub Query SQL for students who never loaned a book

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to introduce a sub-query in MySql.

I have two tables; a loan table and a student table. `student` consists of (Student ID, first name, last name, street, town, city, course), and `loan` consists of (loan Id, copy ID, student ID). Tables are linked via the `StudentId`.

I want to create a sub-query of students who have not loaned a book.

Currently I have tried...

```
SELECT CONCAT(fName, '', lName) AS 'Student Name'
FROM Student
WHERE studentId IN (SELECT studentId FROM loan WHERE studentId IS NULL);
```

The above code just returns nothing. I am all out of ideas at this point and any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(fName, '', lName) AS 'Student Name'
FROM Student s
left join Loan l on s.studentId = l.studentId
where l.studentId is null
```

Basically what it's doing is attempting to join on `loan` from `student` and showing only the `student` records that ***don't*** successfully join onto `loan`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
SELECT CONCAT(fName, '', lName) AS 'Student Name'
FROM Student
WHERE studentId NOT IN (SELECT studentId
            FROM loan);
```

Comment: it's my pleasure :)- @BernardBonjoThompson